# Columns dont inherit width when contained in div

Tags: html, xml, xslt, pdf, xslt-1.0

Lets say we have a table with many rows. When transforming my XML to a PFD via XSLT I want certain rows to not split across a page break. At the moment I have

```
<table>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <div style="page-break-inside:avoid">
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
  </div>
  <tr>...</tr>
</table>
```

That works well to a point. Porblem is that the columns within the div nolonger inherit their widths from the first row in the table as normal.

Is there anything I can do with the div to maintian the inheritance? Or should I try a different approach?

Comment: This is invalid syntax... `<div>` can't be a child of a `<table>`.  (Officially neither can `<tr>` as it should be in a `<tbody>` or `<thead>`, but that is by-the-by, as most - if not all - browsers allow it)

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to do some reading up on my table syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is invalid HTML syntax to have `<div>` as a child of `<table>`.

Try this instead...

```
<table>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr style="page-break-inside:avoid">...</tr>
  <tr style="page-break-inside:avoid">...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
</table>
```

Or better still, set it via CSS - either against all `<tr>` elements...

```
<style type="text/css">
  tr { page-break-inside:avoid }
</style>
```

... or set `class="myTR"` as an attribute of the `<tr>`, and then...

```
<tr class="myTR">...</tr>

<style type="text/css">
  .myTR { page-break-inside:avoid }
</style>
```

Comment: Ah thank-you. My knowledge of HTML has withered over the years.

Comment: Not a problem @Horba. Please remember SO runs under a system of [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation). If my answer was helpful, please consider [upvoting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130054/188605). If my answer was the solution to your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/188605)

Comment: I have done, also found a solution to my specific problem. Use <tbody> instead of <div>. Gives the expected functionality.